# Would anyone be able to guide me in a Flex 4.6 sql issue?

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6

I am currently following a training video to learn Flex and I am trying to stay as close to the video directions as possible,  I have been trying to figure out how to fix the error

Error #2044: Unhandled SQLErrorEvent:. errorID=3115, operation=execute , message=Error #3115: SQL Error. , details=no such table: 'archivelist'

The table Should according to the training be created with this code.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.utils.OnDemandEventDispatcher;

        public var ArchiveFile:File;
        public var dbConnection:SQLConnection;



        private function createDatabase():void
        {
            ArchiveFile = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("archive.db");
            dbConnection = new SQLConnection();
            dbConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onDatabaseOpen);
            dbConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.CLOSE, onDatabaseClose);

            dbConnection.openAsync(ArchiveFile);
        }

        private function onDatabaseOpen(evt:SQLEvent):void
        {
            trace("Database is now open");
            var statement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            statement.sqlConnection = dbConnection;
            statement.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archivelist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT , journal TEXT)";

            statement.execute();

            }       

        private function onDatabaseClose(evt:SQLEvent):void
        {
            trace("Database is now closed");
        }

        private function saveJournal():void
        {

            var statement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            statement.sqlConnection = dbConnection;
            statement.text = "INSERT INTO archive (title , journal) VALUES ('"+title_txt.text+"','"+journal_txt.text+"')";

            statement.execute();

            title_txt.text = "";
            journal_txt.text = "";

        }


    ]]>
```

### Then be called on another view with this code

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.data.SQLConnection 
        import flash.filesystem.File
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        public var ArchiveFile:File
        public var dbConnection:SQLConnection;
        public var selectQuery:SQLStatement;

        private function createDatabase():void
        {
            ArchiveFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("archive.db");
            dbConnection = new SQLConnection();
            dbConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onDatabaseOpen);
            dbConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.CLOSE, onDatabaseClose);

            dbConnection.openAsync(ArchiveFile)
        }

        private function onDatabaseOpen(evt:SQLEvent):void
        {
            trace("Database is now open");
            selectQuery = new SQLStatement();
            selectQuery.sqlConnection = dbConnection;
            selectQuery.text = "SELECT * FROM archivelist ORDER BY title ASC";
            selectQuery.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, onQueryResult);   

            selectQuery.execute();  
        }

        private function onQueryResult(evt:SQLEvent):void
        {
            archivefiles.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(selectQuery.getResult().data);
        }

        private function onDatabaseClose(evt:SQLEvent):void
        {
            trace("Database is now Closed");
        }

    ]]>
```

it is important to note that in the video the trainer has a blue file under views called database.db   They have not provided this file or how to make it.   For my own means i have renamed my database to archive  and my table to archivelist.  my ultimate goal is to make 1 database that multiple views can access / write to.  with best practices so I am trying to stay as close to the training as possible.  I greatly appreciate any help given.  I apologize in advance if anyone feels this is a newbish question I have researched this on google and checked every character with the training video for a couple hours. I find everyone seems to have a different way and I am trying to do the BEST PRACTICE way.

thank you

Comment: can someone please help?

Comment: I personally haven't worked with this directly perhaps linking to the video you used will help though.

Comment: its a paid video. Mobile Development with Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 and Flash Builder 4.5: Learn by Video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use async mode for database interactive so that your UI never freeze.

Error #2044: Unhandled SQLErrorEvent. Due to the you should not open Async mode it should be sync mode (I think you try to work in SYNC mode)

```
dbConnection.open(ArchiveFile); //  not openAsync(ArchiveFile);
```

or You need handle SQLErrorEvent like

```
dbConnection.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onDatabaseCloseError);
```

BEST WAY :

1) You need to read about DAO Pattern(Sun Java)

2) Use single connection for your whole application so make your sqlconnection visible in your all DAO Class (Sqlite doesn't support concurreny so use single connection).

3) If use use connection pooling performance will boost up but having issue like Database file currently locking.

4) Use Parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection.(Also it increase performance)

If you want sample application please follow this link http://coenraets.org/blog/2008/02/salesbuilder-for-air-10/
This guys make excellent utils for sql query also make sure that 2 version are there try to get Async Database operation Salesbuilder application

Please copy and paste it . It will work as you expect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        protected function btnGetArchiveList_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            getArchiveList();
        }

        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            createDatabase();               
        }

        private var ArchiveFile:File
        private var dbConnection:SQLConnection;
        private var selectQuery:SQLStatement;

        private function createDatabase():void
        {
            ArchiveFile = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("archive.db"); //Note here best practices to create db file here applicationStorageDirectory
            dbConnection = new SQLConnection();
            dbConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onDatabaseOpen);
            dbConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.CLOSE, onDatabaseClose);
            dbConnection.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onDatabaseError);
            dbConnection.openAsync(ArchiveFile)
        }

        protected function onDatabaseError(event:SQLErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.error.getStackTrace());
        }

        private function onDatabaseOpen(evt:SQLEvent):void
        {
            trace("Database is now open");
            var statement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            statement.sqlConnection = dbConnection;
            statement.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archivelist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT , journal TEXT)";
            statement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, onTableCreate_ResultHandler);   
            statement.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onDatabaseError);
            statement.execute();;
        }

        protected function onTableCreate_ResultHandler(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            trace("Table created successfully") // Here after only you need to call all query like getArchiveList()
        }

        private function getArchiveList():void
        {
            trace("Getting ArchiveList");
            var selectQuery:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            selectQuery.sqlConnection = dbConnection;
            selectQuery.text = "SELECT * FROM archivelist ORDER BY title ASC";
            selectQuery.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, onQueryResult);   
            selectQuery.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onDatabaseError);   
            selectQuery.execute();
        }

        private function onQueryResult(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            archivefilesList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(((event.currentTarget) as SQLStatement).getResult().data);
        }

        private function onDatabaseClose(evt:SQLEvent):void
        {
            trace("Database is now Closed");
        }

        private function saveJournal():void
        {
            var statement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            statement.sqlConnection = dbConnection;
            statement.text = "INSERT INTO archivelist (title , journal) VALUES ('"+txtTitle.text+"','"+txtJournal.text+"')"; //Note here archivelist table name
            statement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, onInsertQuery_ResultHandler);   
            statement.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onDatabaseError);   
            statement.execute();
            txtTitle.text = "";
            txtJournal.text = "";

        }

        protected function btnSave_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            saveJournal();              
        }

        protected function onInsertQuery_ResultHandler(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            var isInserted:Boolean = ((event.currentTarget) as SQLStatement).getResult().rowsAffected > 0;

            if(isInserted)
                trace("inserted successfully")
            else
                trace("insert failed");

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>
<s:TextInput id="txtTitle"/>
<s:TextInput id="txtJournal"/>
<s:Button id="btnSave" label="Save" click="btnSave_clickHandler(event)"/>

<s:Button id="btnGetArchiveList" label="Get Archive" click="btnGetArchiveList_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:List id="archivefilesList" labelField="title" width="200" height="300"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: making the dbConnection.open(ArchiveFile); in over 600 characters of error the main new error after that change is SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'no such table: 'archivelist'', operation:'execute', detailID:'2013'

Comment: Thank you checking out the link now;   I gotta say going from a non developer to a "want to be developer in training" I took a lot of apps for granted !

Comment: I noticed right off the top that is AIR 1.0 I am using 3.0 would that still work I remember reading AIR 3.0 is a completely different engine.

Comment: Please make sure that after creating database file and CREATE Query executed or not. After that only you need to call SELECT query

Comment: I am sorry I am very new and am not sure i understand what you are saying give me a minute to get you error logs

Comment: [SWF] journal.swf - 3,578,517 bytes after decompression
Database is now open
SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'no such table: 'alist'', operation:'execute', detailID:'2013

Comment: at flash.data::SQLStatement/internalExecute()
 at flash.data::SQLStatement/execute()
 at views::ArchiveView/onDatabaseOpen()[C:\Simplicity Journal\src\views\ArchiveView.mxml:38]

Comment: at flash.data::SQLConnection/internalOpen()
 at flash.data::SQLConnection/open()
 at views::ArchiveView/createDatabase()[C:\Simplicity Journal\src\views\ArchiveView.mxml:27]
 at views::ArchiveView/___ArchiveView_View1_creationComplete()[C:\Simplicity Journal\src\views\ArchiveView.mxml:4]

Comment: at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
 at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1818]

Comment: at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:842]
 at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]

Comment: who ever new creating a DB could become so hard?  I have been working on this one issue for 7 hours now :(

Comment: Please let me know you need async or sync mode database operation. Im mean you want to run first example or second one. I will try to help

Comment: ASYNC  is what the video is saying.  would you be willing to discuss this on skype?  if so please add mrkitty4891  >.>  it was a FFXIV thing....

Comment: goodnight all ill continue working on this till it is resolved in the morning :)